# apposition: The baby tiger Bobo

Tags: appositives

I'd like to know which of the following is good English:

> a. **The baby tiger Bobo** weighs 20 kilos now.
>
> b. **Bobo the baby tiger** weighs 20 kilos now.

If there is more than one baby tiger in the zoo, can b still be used?

Comment: They are both fine. In [a] "Bobo" is the appostive modifier of "baby tiger". Proper names can occur as head with a definite NP as appositive, as in [b].

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical and idiomatic, and there is no problem with using #2 if there is more than one baby tiger in the zoo, just as you could say "Harry Kane, the Tottenham footballer".

Comment: Why "the" in your "Harry Kane, the Tottenham footballer" example, if there is more than one Tottenham footballer?

Comment: For the same reason we say "Neil Armstrong, *the* astronaut" so that he is not confused with Neil Armstrong, the carpet salesman.  We are *specifying* which one we mean and expect the listener to know of or expect the listener to be interested in, as a topic of conversation.  We use **the** for all the reasons opposite those which ask for **a**.  I don't want to presume, but for the sake of example, I might say to your grandmother "His favorite player is Harry Kane, **a** Tottenham footballer" if I didn't expect her to know already who Harry Kane is.